# Pinch to zoom broken with google maps on chrome pixel

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, touchscreen

Is there anyway to get pinch zoom gestures working when using google maps as a third-party tool? Touch gestures work on [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com), but not when included as a plugin like the [simple map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).

Comment: Hello Corey. Did you find any workaround for this issue?